# NSolve does not return a value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm interested in obtaining the KKT multipliers in a constrained optimization problem. I've checked the `NMaximize` documentation, but I've been unable to find how to recover the multipliers. As an alternative, I've tried `NSolve` on the FOCs and Mathematica stalls (even though `NMaximize` does return a solution).

The code is as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
T = {{2, 3, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 3}};
techniques = Dimensions[T][[1]];
factors = Dimensions[T][[2]];
αVec = ConstantArray[4/6, techniques];
λVec = Array[λ, techniques];
γVec = Array[γ, factors];
μVec = Array[μ, techniques];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, techniques];
zerosVec = ConstantArray[0, techniques];
needs = Transpose[T].λVec^(1/αVec);
FactorNeeds[mix_] := Transpose[T].mix^(1/αVec);

λcritical = Table[λVec /.
Flatten[
  Minimize[{needs[[j]], onesVec.λVec == 1, 
    onesVec >= λVec >= zerosVec}, λVec, Reals]][[
 2 ;; techniques + 1]], {j, 1, factors}];

NMaximize[{λVec.onesVec,needs <= FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{0, 1, 0}],onesVec >= λVec >= zerosVec}, λVec, Reals]

MatrixForm[Flatten[{D[λVec.onesVec + γVec.(needs - 
    FactorNeeds[
     Transpose[λcritical].{0, 1, 
       0}]) + μVec.λVec, {λVec}],Table[γVec[[s]] (needs - 
    FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{1, 0, 0}])[[s]], {s,
  1, factors}],Table[μVec[[s]] λVec[[s]], {s, 1, techniques}]}]]


NSolve[Flatten[{D[λVec.onesVec + γVec.(needs - 
     FactorNeeds[
      Transpose[λcritical].{0, 1, 
        0}]) + μVec.λVec, {λVec}], 
Table[γVec[[
   s]] (needs - 
     FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{1, 0, 0}])[[
   s]], {s, 1, factors}], 
Table[μVec[[s]] λVec[[s]], {s, 1, techniques}]}] ==ConstantArray[0, 2*techniques + factors],Flatten[{λVec, γVec, μVec}], Reals]
```

I'm sure my coding can be improved upon, so feel free to comment on it as well. In particular, I think I should be able to do without the definition of either `needs` or `FactorNeeds[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps NSolve needs more information about the solution range.

Try this workaround:

```
eq = Flatten[{D[λVec.onesVec + γVec.(needs -FactorNeeds[Transpose[\ 
[Lambda]critical].{0, 1,0}]) + μVec.λVec, {λVec}],Table[\ 
[Gamma]Vec[[s]] (needs -FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{1, 0, 0}])[[s]], 
{s, 1,factors}], 
Table[μVec[[s]] λVec[[s]], {s, 1, techniques}]}] == 
ConstantArray[0, 2*techniques + factors]
```

NMinimize has a very robust equation solver

```
NMinimize[{1, eq}, Flatten[{λVec, γVec, μVec}]]
(*{1., {λ[1] -> 0.504511, λ[2] ->0.707354, λ[3] -> 0.176838, 
λ[4] ->0.163564, γ[1] -> -4.7945*10^-9, γ[2] -> -0.145919, 
γ[3] -> -0.500829, μ[1] -> 5.87935*10^-8, μ[2] ->6.94144*10^-8, 
μ[3] ->-5.16111*10^-7, μ[4] -> -6.38508*10^-7}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting to obtain the same results (for the $\lambda$s) than `NMaximize` does. Maybe I've made a mistake in my FOCs, I'll check. Also, I don't understand your use of `NMinimize`here. Why do you use it and what is the purpose of the 1?

Comment: It is a kind of misuse  of NMinimize, which try to minimize the constant `1` thereby fullfilling the constraint `eq` .  `NMinimize` searchs a global real solution.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this (look at the command Thread[] and to the change $\{0.,1.,0.\},\{1.,0.,0.\}$ instead of $\{0,1,0\},\{1,0,0\}$)

```
NMaximize[{λVec.onesVec, Thread[needs <= FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{0., 1., 0.}]],Thread[onesVec >= λVec >= zerosVec]}, λVec, Reals]


NSolve[Thread[Flatten[{D[λVec.onesVec + γVec.(needs - 
FactorNeeds[
       Transpose[λcritical].{0., 1., 0.}]) + μVec.λVec, {\ 
[Lambda]Vec}], 
Table[γVec[[s]] (needs - FactorNeeds[Transpose[λcritical].{1., 0., 0.}])[[s]], {s, 1, factors}], 
Table[μVec[[s]] λVec[[s]], {s, 1, techniques}]}] == ConstantArray[0, 2*techniques + factors]], 
Flatten[{λVec, γVec, μVec}], Reals]
```

giving the result

```
{{λ[1] -> 0.167225, λ[2] -> 0.376255, λ[3] -> 
0.0940638, λ[4] -> 1.50502, μ[1] -> 0, μ[2] -> 
0, μ[3] -> 0, μ[4] -> 0, γ[1] -> 
0, γ[2] -> -0.543422, γ[3] -> 0}, {λ[1] -> 
0.671919, λ[2] -> 0.671919, λ[3] -> 
0.16798, λ[4] -> 0.0746576, μ[1] -> 0, μ[2] -> 
0, μ[3] -> 0, μ[4] -> 0, γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 
0, γ[3] -> -0.813299}, {λ[1] -> 
0.504511, λ[2] -> 0.707353, λ[3] -> 
0.176838, λ[4] -> 0.163564, μ[1] -> 0, μ[2] -> 
0, μ[3] -> 0, μ[4] -> 0, γ[1] -> 
0, γ[2] -> -0.145918, γ[3] -> -0.50083}, {λ[
1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 
0}, {λ[1] -> 0, λ[2] -> 0, λ[3] -> 
0, λ[4] -> 
0, μ[1] -> -1., μ[2] -> -1., μ[3] -> -1., μ[
4] -> -1., γ[1] -> 0, γ[2] -> 0, γ[3] -> 0}}
```

Comment: Why do we need to `Thread` the inequality instead of using vector inequalities?

Comment: @Patricio Is NSolve returning now the due result?

Comment: No, it still stalls

Comment: @Patricio Did you noticed that in my script I represent $\{0.,1.,0.\}$ instead $\{0,1,0\}$ and $\{1.0,0.0,0.0\}$ instead $\{1,0,0\}$ ? Try that.